# Wrapping long titles in a fieldset?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I wrap very long titles in a form and a fieldset?

I took this code from Sencha's docs and simply added a long title, and added a width.  Unfortunately, the title is truncated with ellipsis.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Here's the modified Sencha source: (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?',
            width: 300,
            instructions: 'Tell us all about yourself',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'firstName',
                    label: 'First Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'lastName',
                    label: 'Last Name'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Ext.field.Field labelWrap config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Field-cfg-labelWrap).

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?',
            width: 300,
            instructions: 'Tell us all about yourself',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'firstName',
                    label: 'First Name',
                    labelWrap : true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'lastName',
                    label: 'Last Name',
                    labelWrap : true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

### EDIT

Sorry, I misread part of that.

I will in no way claim to be a CSS expert...however this worked for me:

```
.x-form-fieldset-title {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

That will affect each of your title, you may want to try and single out just the title that is too long.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: That wraps the labels.  How about the long title?  "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck..."

Comment: I edited my answer to include a css addition that should fix you.